# Selenium TakesScreenshot capturing "Please wait..." Message

Tags: java, selenium

I'm using the code below to capture a screenshot of every page of a website. It works but sometimes certain pages load 1 to 2 second/s late, and I get photobombed by a spinning gif circle with a "Please wait..." message.

```
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("c:\\tmp\\screenshot.png"));
```

Using Firebug, it looks like this may be the culprit:

```
<div class="blockUI blockMsg blockPage" style="z-index: 1011; position: fixed;
padding: 15px; margin: 0px; width: 20%; top: 40%; left: 40%; text-align: center; 
color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: medium none; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); 
cursor: wait; opacity: 0;">
<img src="/images/front/loading.gif"/>
<br/>
<strong>Please wait...</strong>
</div>`
```

My question is: how do I time my screenshot to avoid this? Thread.sleep(2000) works, but I'd rather stay away from that. I've also checked for the presence of elements on the page, and they are there, but this message gets in the way.

Appreciate any advice. Thanks.

***Edited to add some code (from Firebug) that got cut-off.*

Comment: If the loading screen is caused by JQuery, you can check to see if JQuery is currently running by running this javascript command: `return jQuery.active == 0`.  Alternatively, you could wait until the elements are visible, not just present.

Comment: @MrTi, thanks for the `jQuery.active` tip. It pointed me in the right direction and with some googling, led me to [Hedley Proctor's](http://hedleyproctor.com/2012/07/effective-selenium-testing/) solution. Specifically, the `waitForAjax.java` part.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try waiting until the 'Please wait...' element is invisible?

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//strong[text()='Please wait...']"));
```

Comment: I've tried something similar using `By.id`. The problem though is an implicit wait earlier in the code for 30 seconds. 
`driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`
Even if I set the WebDriverWait to 10 seconds, it will use the full 30 seconds before it returns anything.
`WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);`

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using that `implicit wait` earlier in your code? They can usually be more trouble than they are worth and the `explicit wait` is, typically, a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

We can use this for latest versions of Internet Explorer 10+:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementWithText(
      By.xpath("//div[2]/div[contains(text(),'Please Wait....')]"),"Please Wait...."));
```